# What is an "Unregistered" user?

Tags: discussion

I was just going through questions on TGO, and I came across this.

[image]

What does "Unregistered" mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I believe it refers to a user who hasn't created an account, which is what the registration process does.

As you can see in my picture, which, unfortunately, is not great quality, it says that anyone is welcome to ask or answer a question, whether or not they have an account. In the black line at the top, it gives you the option to sign up, however, it isn't required for participation. (There are certain sites that require registration in order to post answers, which are listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227111/why-are-guests-not-allowed-to-post-question-but-allowed-to-post-answers)).

Being unregistered allows for a certain amount of anonymity (for instance, you can't search for her name under Users), and has a few other benefits, although some of those same things can be drawbacks. For more information, check out the questions tagged [unregistered-users](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unregistered-users) on [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unregistered-users).

[image]